# How can I call environment variables on the Front-End Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase

I have a login page that will only require a password. I am using the email/password to authorize the user but do not want to show the user the email associated with the account. How can I call an environment variable on the front-end? I am using Firebase web libraries and js.

I have attempted to call

```
firebase.functions().config().login.email
```

get an error firebase.functions().config() is not function

```
functions.config().login.email
```

functions is not defined

Comment: What do you mean that you don't want the user to show associated email but at the same time use it to authorize?

Comment: I am using the auth like this firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('name@email.com', 'password123').catch(function (error) {});
but instead of showing the email in javascript I want to use an enviroment variable.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around it... Do I understand correctly that you want to decide for which user the user will login upon deployment of your app? May ask why?

Comment: We are building an exclusive order page and we will be printing an access code on a brochure. I want to use Firebases auth to log them in but just do not want to show an email if possible. Thank you for the responses btw.

Comment: Thanks for response. `firebase.functions().config()`comes from `firebase-admin` that is designed for server use. You could use a Firebase Function to run this code, and call it from your webpage (in some secure way) BUT if you want to use email per cupon, config seems to be useless as you can only have one project configuration at a time? How the users come to the login page? By retyping URL from printed cupon or you redirect them from somewhere e.g. email (you have the email so perhaps that what happens). Can't you just pass the email when redirecting a user to the login page?

Comment: I will try a cloud function instead thank you for your help.